# How to create a google keep/google photos like layout in flutter where the list of child widgets heights is dynamic?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a flutter layout where the child widgets heights are dynamically and would like to auto wrap to next row.
However, when using Wrap widget its show blank line as show in screenshot!

My requirement is more of google keep or google photos where the child widgets are of dynamic height still the parent layout can auto arrange items without any gaps between the content.

[image: Wrap with dynamic card height]

[image: This gap shouldn't exist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can you this [StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package for this requirement